# SQUID Proxy "The request or reply is too large"

Tags: squid

When I am using squid proxy in the server, I get an error message, "The request or reply is too large" from any node in the LAN.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

This error message appears when you try downloading large file using GET or uploading it using POST/PUT. There are several parameters to look for:

```
request_body_max_size

reply_body_max_size
```

These two are set to 0 by default, which means no limits at all. They should not be limited unless you really know how that affects your squid behavior. Or at all in standard proxy.

```
request_header_max_size

reply_header_max_size
```

These two default to 64kB starting from Squid-3.1. Earlier versions of Squid had defaults as low as 2 kB. In some rather rare circumstances even 64kB is too low, so you can increase this value.

from [wiki sqid faq](http://wiki.squid-cache.org)